# What is the exact VIO implementation on Google ARCore

Tags: arcore

is there any source (paper/report/code/etc) explaining the exact Visual-Inertial-Odometry (VIO) implementation that is being used in ARCore for tracking the user's motion? I would like to see how it compares to other State-of-the-Art approaches in this research field.

Answer (score 1):

In https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/archive/v1.22.0.zip the file arcore_c_api.h has some links, but when I see any ::'s its rough reading...